# Old wood stock - black spots

Tags: antique, cleaning

I’m refinishing an old Stevens 315 shotgun. (Mfg in 1938)

The wood appears to be maple. I stripped any old finish and sanded to 220.

However, there still appears to be some type of embedded grease or maybe tannins?

I’ve sanded the wood, used oxalic acid, and mineral spirits and nothing seems to take this out.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome back. Going by the first pic alone to me this looks like ingrained grime (basically a less severe manifestation of all the accumulated oil/grease/dirt/carbon that made the edge of the butt *so* dark) and this impression seems to be reinforced by the darker patch of end-grain at the back of the notch. You may be able to get some most of this out by treating with acetone, which is a much stronger degreaser than MS. It won't harm the wood (although it will look plenty dry after just one round of treatment, and this may require multiple rounds to have an effect). [contd]

Comment: Larry Potterfield shows cleaning of oil-impregnated stocks using acetone in one or two of the Midway USA vids on YouTube. You'll have to try it and see, no way to know for sure if this will have the desired effect. Obviously one thought is to just sand more, although obviously there is a finite limit to how much wood you can remove without changing the lines of the stock too much. To go deeper I highly recommend switching to scraping rather than exclusively using sanding. As a gun guy are you familiar with Mark Novak? He's demonstrated how much more effective scraping is than sanding.

Comment: What's the end goal here? If you were aiming to keep the wood fairly blond by using a clear finish (straight oil or varnish, no colourants) then obviously any amount of this remaining is undesirable. But if you're intending to go quite a bit darker by using a tinted/pigmented finish that'll make even the current level of marks far less noticeable.......

Comment: I thanks for the reply graphus!  I have some pretty good grain here so I was thinking about using a dye / stain / topcoat to bring that out. That is the main concern is that these spots will intensify once I apply the dye.  But, they may not. I’d like to use a translucent red for it.

Comment: There'll be a huge difference in outcome between dyeing the wood and using a coloured topcoat (basically what would be called a 'candy coat' in car circles). If this is maple as you think, or birch which can look similar, blotching is a potential issue; if you're not familiar I suggest looking that up before making a decision on which route to take. Spoiler: colour on top is going to be a better option almost certainly, although it does have the one downside that the colour is in the finish and not in the wood so any chip or wear-through in due course reveals the pale wood underneath.